# Create Thumbnails on the fly

Tags: php

The code I have below works fine on localhost but does not create thumbnails on live server.

```
<?php

$orig_directory = "../imagefolder";    //Full image folder
$thumb_directory =  "../imagefolder/thumbfolder";    //Thumbnail folder

/* Opening the thumbnail directory and looping through all the thumbs: */
$dir_handle = @opendir($orig_directory); //Open Full image dirrectory
if ($dir_handle > 1){ //Check to make sure the folder opened

$allowed_types=array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
$file_parts=array();
$ext='';
$title='';
$i=0;

while ($file = @readdir($dir_handle)) {
    /* Skipping the system files: */
    if($file=='.' || $file == '..') continue;

    $file_parts = explode('.',$file);    //This gets the file name of the images
    $ext = strtolower(array_pop($file_parts));

    /* Using the file name (withouth the extension) as a image title: */
    $title = implode('.',$file_parts);
    $title = htmlspecialchars($title);

    /* If the file extension is allowed: */
    if(in_array($ext,$allowed_types)) {

        /* If you would like to inpute images into a database, do your mysql query here */

        /* The code past here is the code at the start of the tutorial */
        /* Outputting each image: */

        $nw = 100;
        $nh = 100;
        $source = "../imagefolder/{$file}";
        $stype = explode(".", $source);
        $stype = $stype[count($stype)-1];
        $dest = "../imagefolder/thumbfolder/{$file}";

        $size = getimagesize($source);
        $w = $size[0];
        $h = $size[1];

        switch($stype) {
            case 'gif':
                $simg = imagecreatefromgif($source);
                break;
            case 'jpg':
                $simg = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
                break;
            case 'png':
                $simg = imagecreatefrompng($source);
                break;
        }

        $dimg = imagecreatetruecolor($nw, $nh);
        $wm = $w/$nw;
        $hm = $h/$nw;
        $h_height = $nh/2;
        $w_height = $nw/2;

        if($w> $h) {
            $adjusted_width = $w / $hm;
            $half_width = $adjusted_width / 2;
            $int_width = $w / $hm;
            imagecopyresampled($dimg,$simg,-$int_width,0,0,0,$adjusted_width,$nh,$w,$h);
        } else {
            imagecopyresampled($dimg,$simg,0,0,0,0,$nw,$nh,$w,$h);
        }
            imagejpeg($dimg,$dest,100);
        }
}

/* Closing the directory */
@closedir($dir_handle);

}
?>

<?php //echo "Thumbnails succesfully created ";
header("Refresh: 0; url=display_thumbs.php");
?>
```

anybody have any idea what is worng with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to look at your file permissions. Make sure the folder with the images and this file have permission to write.

Answer (score 0):

Is your PHP on the live server compiled against GD-1.8 or later? It is required to use:

```
imagecreatefromjpeg
imagecreatefromgif
imagecreatefrompng
```